# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline and embeddable javascript widgets: Where should the js live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading a rails 2.3.9 application and I have a file named `widget.js` that lives at `/public/javascripts/widget.js`.

Users can embed this javascript widget on their own site like so:

```
<script src='http://example.com/javascripts/widget.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
  new Widget({user_id: 1234});
</script>
```

As I understand it, with Rails 3.1 everything under `assets/` is fingerprinted in production so `widget.js` would have a filename like `widget-XXXYYYZZZ.js` and would change every time the file was changed. This means that it wouldn't be possible to give users this embeddable url for the `widget.js` file since it'll change.

How can this be accomplished on rails 3.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just leave your script in `public/javascripts/widget.js` and serve it from `/javascripts/widget.js`. The asset pipeline is optional, you don't have to use it for everything (or anything for that matter).

Comment: Interesting. I had originally tried this using the javascript_path helper in a view and it wasn't returning the reference to the right file. I'm guessing the javascript_path method is only returning files in `/assets/` and not in `/public/javascripts/`. Worst case scenario... I can generate the url to `/javascripts/widget.js` myself I guess.

Comment: @mirthlab: The worst cast scenario isn't that bad for just one file. You could also add your own helper that knows about your exceptions and punts to `javascript_path` for the rest.

Comment: Yeah, great advice all around. Thanks for helping me think this through.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable fingerprinting by putting

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

in config/application.rb or in one of the config/environments/* files.

Comment: I don't want to disable fingerprinting completely. It's useful for what it's meant to do. I want to know how to take what was working before and implement it in a way that is compatible with the asset pipeline and file fingerprinting. If I could disable the digest on a _per file_ basis then this might work.